# Image of a submanifold under a linear map

Tags: differential-geometry, linear-transformations

Let $\mathcal{M}^k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a submanifold and $L: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ linear. What kind of object is the image $L\left(\mathcal{M}^k\right)$?

As an example, consider $\mathcal{M}^2 = \left\{ \left(x, y, z\right) \in \mathbb{R}^3, z=x^2+y^2\right\}$ and $L$ the projection on the $x, z$ plane. Then $L\left(\mathcal{M}\right)=\left\{ \left(x, z\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2, x^2 \ge z \right\}$.

I played a bit with these kinds of objects and my current conjecture is, that they are submanifolds possibly with boundary and perhaps not smooth. I would guess that there is somewhere an entire theory on such objects, since it seems like a rather straightforward idea, but Google does not help since it returns all documents that contain the words submanifold and linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ is injective(i.e. in particular $m=n$), $L(\mathcal{M}^k)$ is a submanifold: One way of characterizing a submanifold is that it is everywhere locally the zero set of a submersion (smooth map whose differential always has full rank), Given a submersion $F$ for $\mathcal{M}^k$ at $x$, $F \circ L^{-1}$ is one for $L\mathcal{M}^k$ at $Lx$, if I am not mistaken.

Concerning the more general situation, consider the submanifold $\mathcal{M}^2$  of $\mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized by
$ (r\cos(\alpha), r\sin(\alpha), \alpha)$ for $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ (a line smoothly rotating and at the same time moving along the $z$-axis. The projection of $\mathcal{M}$ to the $(y,z)$-plane is the set of points $\{ (y,z) : \exists r \in \mathbb{R}: xy=r*\sin(z)\} = \mathbb{R^2} \backslash \{ (y,n \pi), n \in \mathbb{Z}, y \neq 0\}$, which is not a manifold, with or without boundary.  (Right? I think that the points $(0, n\pi)$ causes irrepairable trouble...)

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. I believe one can embed $\mathbb{R}^m$ in a larger vector space, such that there exists a sequence of injective linear transformations such that the limit is $L$ and this gives rise to a sequence of submanifolds such that the limit is $L\left(\mathcal{M}^k\right)$.